# What if my samples are not IIDs?

Tags: time-series, iid

I'm testing my system and getting some results over time (Queues size, wating time, ecc.). When I plot the correlograms they exhibit a high degree of autocorrelation, even for high lags. Now, what are the implications of this? In particular I'd like to know:

- Is confidence interval still reliable or is it biased?
- Are QQ plots reliable?

Finally, if necessary, should I subsample my timeseries to overcome this possible "problem"?

Comment: So you have time series data? What is your goal here? What kind of tests / models are you doing?

Comment: I'm testing an airport schedule policy (using OMNeT++) and I want to get some insights of the system but, like I said, all the time series that I get (for example, the size of a queue over time) are not IIDs. What I'd like to know is if I have to worry about that or it depends on what I want to do. It's the first time that I have to get some statistics in a "professional manner" and I don't want to make measurement error due to the fact I did not considered such an issue

Comment: But what do you plan to do with these time series? Are you trying to use a statistical test? Build a model? If so, details are needed. Just saying CI and QQ plots is not enough information. Also, you might want to explain what OMNeT++ is or how it works, if this is relevant to the analysis.

Comment: OMNeT++ is a discrete event simulator but it doesn't matter here. This said I'm trying to show how the quantities inside my system vary when some input parameter (rates, distributions, batch size) varies. To do this I have the time series that describe the evolution of this quantities over time. My question is: are mean, variance CI influenced by the non IID-ness of the samples over time?
Secondly I'd like to show what distribution those quantities belong to and perform a 2^k r! test; of course, I have the same concerns.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Correlation does affect mean and CI, but it depends on how you are going to do this. What tests / models are you going to use?

Comment: For now I'm referring to CI. Now i report what my professor says: Assume that you have a sample of n IID RVs, and that you compute the sample mean, variance and CI for the mean. Now answer the following question: suppose that you are measuring a system where (you know that) even measures are always equal to the preceding odd measure. In other words, you always get
the same value twice when you measure something. Now, suppose that another system always gives a burst of ten consecutive equal values when measured. Would it be correct to measure a sample of n observations and compute a CI?

Comment: According to CI formula it would not be correct because I cannot inflate my sample by adding values that do not bring any additional information. In other words we are overestimating our CI.

Comment: In your given example you cannot estimate the mean and SE given the usual formulas. As you have figured out, this would return misleading results. If you only have duplicates, you could remove these, however if there is still correlation left with other lags, you need a different approach which takes into account the autocorrelation.